# How to run a stored procedure in EF Core 3.14

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am working on the security and user management of a new platform built entirely in .NET Core.

In particular I am trying to generate a random password for new users. I have loaded a large list of English words into a table and created a stored procedure to select random words from the table and compose a password in the correct-horse-battery-staple format.

The stored procedure (`Passwords.GenerateRandomPassword`) takes no parameters and returns a single line `varchar` column named `password`.

Everything works up to this point. I can run the query directly against the server and it works fine.

I have a method on my userRepository like so:

```
public async Task<string> GenerateRandomPassword()
{

}
```

but I cannot figure out how to get EF Core 3.14 to call this stored procedure and return a value.

Documentation may not be up to date, or maybe I'm missing an assembly reference.

The context object and the context.database object do not seem to contain any methods that look like they will allow me to execute a stored procedure and retrieve a value.

Documentation seems to suggest that there should be a `FromSQL` method or similar.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use SQL Client Class to run stored procedure.  See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5810/working-with-sql-server-stored-procedures-and-net/

Comment: @jdweng I would normally use sqlclient.  I'm using that everywhere else in the application as I prefer using sprocs and hence my own SQL rather than generated SQL to query a database.  I have user accounts in a separate database from the application data and as it only really has three tables in it, users, roles and userroles I thought it would be a good chance for me to try out EF as I haven't used it in years.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-execute-a-parameterized-stored-procedure-using-entitycommand

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is to call db.Database.GetDbConnection(), which gives you the ADO.NET connection object that you can use directly.

eg

```
var con = (SqlConnection)db.Database.GetDbConnection();
con.Open();
var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "exec ...";
```

There's also the [db.Database.ExecuteSqlxxx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-3.1) methods, which work for simple cases.

Comment: Thanks David - The problem is that i don't have the ExecuteSQL methods on my _context.Database object.

Comment: It's an extension method, so you need a `using` for its namespace to see it eg `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore was already included.  Maybe the extension method has moved?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look at is [keyless entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=fluent-api).

This is a [new feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#reverse-engineering-of-database-views) in EF Core 3.0.

One [usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=fluent-api#usage-scenarios) is to retrieve data from raw sql queries.

Using **PostgreSQL**.

In PostgreSQL we create a function to generate a password:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_password() RETURNS text AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT substring(md5(random()::text) from 0 for 12));
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

We create our entity:

```
public class PasswordGenerator
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

In our application's DbContext we [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=fluent-api#defining-keyless-entity-types) our entity:

```
public DbSet<PasswordGenerator> PasswordGenerator { get; set; }

public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) 
    : base(options)
{}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PasswordGenerator>().HasNoKey();
}
```

We use the `FromSqlRaw` method to call our function that returns our password:

```
public async Task<string> GetGeneratedPassword()
{
    var pg = await _context.PasswordGenerator
        .FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * from generate_password() AS ""Password""")
        .FirstAsync();

    return pg.Password;
}
```

We use the alias "Password" to correctly map our query to our entity.

The two packages installed are: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`.

Using **SQL Server**.

We create a stored procedure to generate a password:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE generate_password
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT SUBSTRING (CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 12) AS "Password"
    RETURN  
GO
```

Use the alias "Password" to correctly map our query to our entity.

Here's how we use the `FromSqlRaw` method:

```
public async Task<string> GetGeneratedPassword()
{
    var pg = (await _context.PasswordGenerator
        .FromSqlRaw("EXEC generate_password")
        .ToListAsync())
        .First();

    return pg.Password;
}
```

LINQ queries expect our raw queries to be [composable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq), which is why we call `ToListAsync()` right after the `FromSqlRaw` method.

> SQL Server doesn't allow composing over stored procedure calls, so any
>   attempt to apply additional query operators to such a call will result
>   in invalid SQL. Use `AsEnumerable` or `AsAsyncEnumerable` method right
>   after `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated` methods to make sure that EF
>   Core doesn't try to compose over a stored procedure.

The two packages installed are: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

**UPDATE** - Using the `GetDbConnection` method

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61934911/13454322) provided by @David Browne - Microsoft, we can call the `GetDbConnection` extension method to access the database directly.

```
public async Task<string> GetGeneratedPassword()
{
    var password = "";
    var connection = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    try
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            // SQL Server
            command.CommandText = "EXEC generate_password";

            // PostgreSQL
            // command.CommandText = @"SELECT * from generate_password()";
            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    password = reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        await connection.CloseAsync();
    }

    return password;
}
```